# Read updated Xml without restart of Tomcat

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

Please complete my knowledge, I'm having an application that reads some data from an XML at the starting of application. The data read from XML is put into HashMap. The XML is placed in resource folder.

I'm having a requirement that after starting of application, if I made some changes in XML and call the reading XML method, the HashMap should contain updated values. But it is containing previous old values. I want to achieve this without restarting the tomcat server.

Please share by any means I can achieve this.

Comment: It's easy to do with a REST service. Do a POST or PATCH of new values.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm calling a REST service to give signal to application for reading the XML again. Actually I'm updating many values at a time, so avoiding passing values through multiple REST calls. Any other means to get upated XML values?

Comment: No REST is the correct thing. Send the new values in a JSON object and update the Map in one shot.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WatchService API its designed for applications that need to be notified about file change events.

[WatchService API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)